# SSRS reports column behaves differently on different environment.

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-4

I have a report developed in SSRS 2008 R2 for CRM 4.0. The report has a tablix with an email address column. The email address text box appears to wrap text in one environment. But when the same .rdl file is uploaded to another environment for CRM, text wrapping is not visible when the report is run from different environment. Please let me know if anyone has faced this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Are both environments accessing the same instance of SSRS? If not, check the version of SSRS in both environments and make sure that they are the same version.

Comment: Version is same(SSRS 2008 R2) for both the environments. The .rdl file when downloaded from the environment where the report appears correct, when uploaded to the another CRM environment, the column expands. This particular column is email field in the tablix and shows word wrap in the correct environment, but the email address apears in the same line for the environment into question. This is making the column to expand. All the properties remains same for the report.